# auto cross covariance in-build function

Tags: python, matlab, octave

auto covariance Ajj(lag) was calculated according to Eqn. (1)

[image]

Index j was used for the z-scales (j = 1, 2, 3), n is the number of amino acids in a sequence, index i is the amino acid position (i = 1, 2, ...n) and l is the lag (l = 1, 2, ...L)

Cross covariances – Cjk(lag) – between two different z-scales, j and k, were calculated according to Eqn.

[image]

How to compute this in matlab or python...

Comment: they're just a dot product between shifted matrices, divided by (n-l), for example, the last one in (numpy) python dot(z[:,:-1],transpose(z[:,1:]))/(n-l) or similar. Assuming "\times" is just scalar multiplication.

Comment: Have you seen the [`xcov`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/xcov.html) MATLAB function?

Comment: Ya I have seen. But don't know if it applies here

Comment: You want to compute the cross-covariance - that is exactly the definition of what `xcov` does... In what way does it not apply?